# Sorting characters inside String

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort the characters alphabetically in a String and when I run my code with the following example: `hello`, then I get: `heeeeeeeeeheeeelheeellhee` instead of `ehllo`. Could smb suggest me what I should fix in my code? Thanks in advance!

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String result = "";
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = kbd.nextLine();

        char[] myArray = input.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++)
            {
                if(myArray[i] > myArray[j])
                {
                    char temp = myArray[j];
                    myArray[j] = myArray[i];
                    myArray[i] = temp;
                    result += myArray[i];
                }
                else 
                    result += myArray[i];
            }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Comment: What is the result supposed to be?

Comment: `result += myArray[i];` <- Not needed.  Instead, once you've completed the sort, create a new `String` from the `myArray`

Comment: A fun way to do this would be to put all the characters into a TreeSet and then iterate over the contents.

Comment: @dnault Or use `Arrays.sort`, but I don't think that's the point of the exercise ;)

Comment: Also, I think you will find `for(int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++)` should be `for(int j = 1; j < myArray.length; j++)`

Comment: I could use `Arrays.sort` but would like to do sorting from scratch, i.e. w/o using any ready templates such as `Arrays.sort` or `TreeSet`

Comment: @MadProgrammer, could you please clarify your point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each iteration of your loop, you appending the character at `i` within the array to `result`, but the array is not sorted yet

The loop will perform `n * (n - 1)` loops, so, for a `String` of 5 characters, that's going to be `5 * (5 - 1)` (or 20) iterations.

Instead, sort the array and then create a new `String` based on it's content...

```
String input = "hello";

char[] myArray = input.toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < myArray.length; j++) {
        if (myArray[i] > myArray[j]) {
            char temp = myArray[j];
            myArray[j] = myArray[i];
            myArray[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(new String(myArray));
```

Also note, `for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {` is wrong and should be `for (int j = 1; j < myArray.length; j++) {`, otherwise you'll be comparing the same character at the same position, which isn't what you want to do...

A more "accurate" bubble sort might look something like...

```
for (int i = 0; i < (myArray.length - 1); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length - i - 1; j++) {
        if (myArray[j] > myArray[j + 1]) {
            char swap = myArray[j];
            myArray[j] = myArray[j + 1];
            myArray[j + 1] = swap;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, @MadProgrammer.But now the problem is it's not sorting properly alphabetically. If I do `hello`, it gives me `eollh`.

Comment: @John Then you need to look into how your sort is working.  If I don't correct the for the inner for-loop I get `ollhe` instead ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated?

```
public String sortByChar(String s)
{
    char[] cs = s.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(cs);
    return new String(cs);
}
```

Comment: Exercise is to better know Java not manually implement some "bubble sort" mechanism. Knowing Collections and their abilities is good goal for exercises,

Answer (score 0):

You keep modifying `result` as you go. This is wrong: `result` collects a record of characters as you modify them, which is not what you want.

You should remove `result += ...` from your code, and use this after the loop:

```
String result = new String(myArray);
```